# Updating KMDF Driver Without Windows Restart

Tags: windows, driver, kmdf

I recently wrote a KMDF Driver in windows using Visual Studios. I then proceeded to locally install the driver whilst in TestMode (e.g., `devcon install driver.inf hwid`). Cool so the driver is running, and I can see the driver Callbacks firing in `Dbgview.exe`.

But now I have a bug in my driver. So I write some code, build the new driver, and now I want to restart it. So I attempt to use `devcon` to update to my new driver. However, upon doing so `devcon` reminds me that I need to perform a system restart in order for the change to take effect. This is really painful for debugging a new version of the driver (Please don't suggest using a VM/Remote target machine , I'm not interested in this solution).

Is there anyway to update the driver without restarting Windows?

Note, i can see that there is a "Driver Service" running for my driver but I'm unable to stop it. I wonder if this service is preventing me from updating my driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you install your driver via DevCon using the INF file, the driver is a PnP one. Unlike legacy drivers, PnP drivers cannot be stopped directly. You need to disable all devices controlled by the driver, and PnP Manager will unload the driver automatically.

To disable a device, you can use the appropriate DevCon command, or do it in Device Manager.

Comment: Great start. However, when attempting to disable the device I get pop-up asking me to restart Windows to disable the device. Is there a way to disable the device without the need to restart? I mean, I wrote the driver, and if something has to change there, then I'm curious what that might be. Otherwise, would it make sense to load my driver using a different method?

Comment: I think I may have found my answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/irp-mn-query-remove-device